# What is the command line for Indexing Options?

Tags: windows-7, command-line

What is the command line for Indexing Options? I very much enjoyed reading all *five* pages of [Useful Commandline Commands on Windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-commandline-commands-on-windows). But I still cannot find the console command for Indexing Options.

I have this little, free system tray app called [UriTree](http://uritree.codeplex.com/) that stores these things in an OPML file---so having as many of these command-line tricks as possible helps me personally. Anyway, here is the screenshot of the applet that I *cannot* call from the command-line:

[image: Windows 7 Indexing Options]

Comment: ...sorry about that `.htaccess`...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Type <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, the then run the command:

```
rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL srchadmin.dll
```

I have only tried this on Windows Vista.

Comment: it works on Windows 7 64-bit! great job!

Comment: It works on Windows 10.  Thanks.

Comment: That works to open the window directly. What would be really nice is commands to add directories to the indexed locations directly, without needing to click around in that window.

Comment: thanks, conrol.exe as in `control srchadmin.dll` can replace the first part (calling it with the `Control_RunDLL` function).

Comment: Does it support further arguments? Like getting the current status or pressing that _Pause_ button?

Answer (score 7):

`control.exe srchadmin.dll` opens the "Indexing Options" window in Windows 7 and Windows 10 (so probably also in Win 8).

Answer (score 2):

Outside of a need to open it programmatically, the quickest way to open `Indexing Options` is:

- Hit the <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> Windows Key
- Type `index` and wait a split-second for `Indexing Options` to be highlighted
- Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

:-)

Answer (score 0):

> Type "index" and wait a split-second for ...

As search query points to here i forced to note, that some people does not find "index options" just because the recommended "index" search query gives them nothing, because the tool in win7 is not localized properly.

You should search the system tool name of control panel only in language selected as primary (not by system name of the tool).

[here could be example image](http://f26.ifotki.info/org/4ab4f762987667c31428fa8b2e05d0c957fd14413361680.png)

As contrary example, win7 explorer takes both: original directory name "c:\users" and localized directory name "c:???????".