# Is indexing by file extension possible in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

#### Current Version of Windows

```
OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version 10.0.18362 Build 18362
```

#### Indexing Options

If I open up the indexing options using the [very good example shown here](https://superuser.com/questions/71009/what-is-the-command-line-for-indexing-options).

#### Question

There are only options that I can see to index folders without any further customisation like file extensions.

The reason is, that I've reformated my PC and have gotten all the possible portable apps I could get and place them in one path like so `W:\Apps (Portable)` and I only want to index by file extension such as `.exe`. This would prevent any other non-crital files to appear in any searches via the start menu.

Would there be a location in the registry where there could be modifications done to it to allow only `.exe` files to appear in in the start menus search?

#### Here's a screenshot of the folder structure I'm working with.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no option to change Windows *Search* to find only executables. However, you can *save* a Windows search that would display all executables sorted as you want.

- Open Windows *File Explorer* to `W:\Apps (Portable)` by double-clicking it.
- In the *Search* box, type `ext:exe`.
- Sort the results on a column, e.g., `Filename`.
- Drag the "pages" icon from the address bar to the desktop.

Any time you need to find those apps, reopen the saved search. Click in a blank area on the right pane and start typing a filename; it will scroll to it.

The data kept is search criteria, so the it's executed each time it's opened. A wee bit slow, but it finds any changed files.

Comment: This would be a great workaround if there was a way to limit the nested folders windows goes through. 4 subfolder deep would be a good sweet spot as it's digging too far like this example `W:\Apps (Portable)\Utilities\Utilities (Apps Folder)\cmder\vendor\git-for-windows\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-config.exe`. But, I not only use File Explorer but Freecommander too and I'm only after finding out it's possible to create a file container which is proprietary to FC using [Find](https://freecommander.com/fchelpxe/en/Search.html#_Suchen)... _cont_

Comment: ... and then with those search results: **File → Export to file container** to create a container. This has to be searched and a new [file container](https://freecommander.com/fchelpxe/en/FileContainerTab.html) created every time there's a change.

Comment: I suppose another workaround would be to type `app:stickies` in the start menu search or `stickies`  then click on the **Apps** tab.