# How can I gracefully stop the Windows Search service via console?

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, windows-search, search-indexing

I use the following PowerShell cmdlets to stop the Windows Search service:

```
Set-Service -Name WSearch -StartupType Disabled
Stop-Service -Name WSearch
```

But if I do that while the Windows Search service is indexing files, the index database will become corrupted. So, just stopping the Windows Search service does not seem to gracefully shut it down.

In the GUI, I can pause the indexing for 15 minutes by pressing the *Pause* button:

[image: Indexing Options]

If I then shutdown the Windows Search service, the index database does *not* become corrupted.

**So, is there a way, I can pause the indexing operation by console commands?**

There is a way to open the GUI window via console, but it does not seem to be possible to pass further arguments ([source](https://superuser.com/a/1196481/1077440)):

```
control srchadmin.dll
```

Besides that, I am not looking for a solution that automates clicking inside a GUI, as I need to run the script without any GUI available. My goal is to automate the defragmentation of the index database, which requires the database to be *offline*.

Comment: Does `net stop cisvc` corrupt the db? You can start it again with `net start cisvc`.

Comment: You have explained *what* you want to achieve. Can you explain, by editing the question, *why* you want that?

Comment: @Gantendo I added my goal. `cisvc.exe` does not exist on my Windows version.

Comment: ah yeah its called wsearch nowadays I forgot. Go to https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/reset-rebuild-windows-search-index-fix-problems/ and search for "Defrag the Search index database Windows.edb to reduce the file size"

Comment: @Gantendo That was actually one of my sources already ;-) But as stated, the index database will be damaged by stopping `WSearch` if there is an ongoing indexing operation.

Comment: `Set-Service -Name WSearch -Status Paused` ?

Comment: @Theo That's not supported. You'll get the following error message: `Service 'Windows Search (WSearch)' cannot be suspended because the service does not support being suspended or resumed.`

Comment: Hmmm. Pitty. Weird though, because you _can_ Pause the indexing in the gui...